# having trouble passing in a variable from one function to another in python

Tags: python-3.x, function, variables, parameters

i wanted to pass in one variable i made in one function into another function in order to print it out and do stuff with it , however i'm having trouble trying to pass the variable i made in the first function into the second function

```
courses = [{k: json_dict[k] for k in keep_keys}
                    for json_dict in specific_major]
return courses
```

the courses variable that is above is what i want to use in my next function. i tried returning it and then making a new function and passing it in as a function.

```
def classes_get(c):
    print(c)

classes_get(courses)
```

i tried the following code above in jupyter notebook to see if it would print out but i always get this message 
"courses not defined" even though i run all the code blocks in order and the course variable prints out normally when i call the first function its in. is there a step i'm missing that isn't allowing me to use it in another function?

```
def get_departments():
    umd_departments = requests.get("https://api.umd.io/v0/courses/departments")
    umd_departments_list = umd_departments.json()

    umd_departments_list2 = json.dumps(umd_departments_list, indent=1)
    department_storage = [department['dept_id'] for department in umd_departments_list]
    print(department_storage)
    dept = input('what department are you  in right now: ')
    dept = dept.upper()
    if dept not in department_storage:
        raise ValueError("department doesn't exist")
    else:
        department_url = requests.get(f"https://api.umd.io/v0/courses?dept_id={dept}")
        specific_major =department_url.json()
        keep_keys = ["course_id", "name", "credits", "sections"]                        
        courses = [{k: json_dict[k] for k in keep_keys}
                    for json_dict in specific_major]

        return courses
```

edit: get_departments is the first function. sorry for not including all of it

another edit: this is what i tried so far

```
courses = get_departments()
def get_classes(courses):
    print(courses)
get_classes(courses)
```

Comment: Where is the first function?

Comment: just included it in the edit @Vishnudev

Answer (score 0):

Use the returned value from first function and pass it to the other function. If you are using jupyter notebook, ensure that the `get_department` function is defined / run before called `classes_get`.

```
courses = get_departments()
classes_get(courses)
```

Comment: so it should be like this `def classes_get(courses):
    courses = get_departments()
    print(courses)' do we put the courses = get_departments() in the second function when we define it?

Comment: No. You should put it outside. The variable `courses` needs to be defined. Include full traceback of the error.

Comment: i tried that but it didn't work , it just shows the stars even after i clear the output. i edited the post to show what i tried so far  @Vishnudev